# what is the alternate way to count the occurrence of each word without using 'uniq -c' command?

Tags: unix, cut, uniq

Is it possible to count the occurrence of each word like using `uniq -c` but with the count *after* the word rather than before?

### Example scenario

Input file named as `text1.txt` which contain the following data

```
Renault:cilo:84563
Renault:cilo:84565
M&M:Thar:84566
Tata:nano:84567
M&M:quanto:84568
M&M:quanto:84569
```

The fields used in the above data are `car_company`:`car_model`:`customerID`

#### Desired result

```
cilo   2
Thar   1
nano   1
quanto 2
```

(`car_model` and number of cars sold grouped by `car_model`)

#### My code

```sh
cat test1.txt | cut -d: -f2 | uniq -c
```

#### Actual Result

```
   2 cilo   
   1 Thar   
   1 nano   
   2 quanto
```

Is it possible to do the above process without using `uniq -c` ,so that I can swap the order of the fields (columns)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `uniq`, and simply post-process its output to swap the columns:

```
cut -d: -f2 test1.txt | uniq -c | awk '{print $2 "\t" $1 "\n" }'
```

EDIT: Added `\n`, as noted in a comment.

Comment: when i use your code,am getting output in single line like 
**cilo    2Thar    2nano    1quanto     2**
so i have modified the code as `cut -d: -f2 text1.txt | uniq -c | awk '{printf $2 " " $1 "\n"}'`

Answer (score 1):

Save your commands output into a file "badresult";

```
cat test1.txt | cut -d: -f2 | uniq -c > badresult
```

Then cut the seventh field and save it into a file named "counts"(you should use space(" ") as a seperator);

```
cut -d" " -f7 badresult > counts
```

Then cut the eighth field and save it into a file named "models"(you should use space(" ") as a seperator);

```
cut -d" " -f8 badresult > models
```

Now you have your counts and models in seperate files. All you have to do is to show these two files seperately with "pr" command(-m: one file per column, -T:no pre-information)

```
pr -m -T models counts
```

Comment: Thanks Barristan.bit lengthy but simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
cat test1.txt | cut -d: -f2 | uniq -c | awk '{ t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print }'
```

The little awk code exchanges fields 1 and 2 using a temporary.

Answer (score 0):

You just need `awk` for this:

```
$ awk -F: '{a[$2]++} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
cilo 2
quanto 2
nano 1
Thar 1
```

This goes through every line keeping track of how many times the second field has appeared. Since everything is stored in the array `a`, then it is just a matter of looping through it and printing its content.